# What does ⌛︎ Preview Hidden in macOS Messages app mean?

Tags: macos, messages

One of my contacts with whom I exchange iMessages, has started showing **⌛︎ Preview Hidden** in the macOS Messages app just below their name.

[image]

Interestingly, this is not shown in the Messages app on my iPad and iPhone, just the Mac. Also, I have not enabled Hide Alerts for the said contact. I am able to communicate with them normally, and I also receive the notifications for any messages that they send.

My questions are:

1. What does **⌛︎ Preview Hidden** mean?
2. What causes it to get enabled?
3. How to remove/disable it?
4. Does it apply to all the devices linked to my Apple ID and where Messages are enabled?

I use Messages in iCloud, and I am running current up-to-date version of OS on all the devices that I use (macOS Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287) on Mac and iOS/iPadOS 13.4.1 on iPhones/iPads).

Comment: On the bright side, you aren't the only one. Someone on the [Apple Forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251267273) posted a similar question last week.

Comment: By any chance, do you have Parental Control or Screen Time settings enabled? This contact may be setup as a "Restricted Contact".

Comment: @RushilSrivastava No and no.

Comment: @RushilSrivastava Thanks for sharing the link to Apple Support Communities.

Answer (score 2):

I had this too and this seemed to give me what I wanted (the preview):
System Preferences->Notifications->Messages->Show Notification Preview->set to Always. Then Quit Messages and restart.

Comment: Wow. My "Show nofications preview" preference is only a checkbox in 10.15.4. So, I should interpret that preference to mean "do not show a preview and don't show any messages either". Big a** eye roll.